# Pandas ExcelFile sheet_names returns empty list

Tags: python, pandas

As the subject indicates, I'm creating an ExcelFile object from a raw xlsx file on my github and when I call the `.sheet_names` attribute an empty list is returned. There are two sheet names, "Trips" and "Description".

```
ef = pd.ExcelFile("https://github.com/j-on-son/Data/blob/master/ISyE3803/Relay%20Bikes/Relay%20Bikes/Relay%20Trips.xlsx?raw=true")

print(ef.sheet_names) # empty list
df = ef.parse("Trips") # sheet name not found error as expected
df = pd.read_excel("https://github.com/j-on-son/Data/blob/master/ISyE3803/Relay%20Bikes/Relay%20Bikes/Relay%20Trips.xlsx?raw=true", \
     sheet_name = "Trips") # sheet name not found error
```

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I searched looking for something similar and couldn't find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue here is your source file is defective,

if you use `openpyxl`

```
import openpyxl 

openpyxl.load(("https://github.com/j-on-son/Data/blob/master/ISyE3803/Relay%20Bikes/Relay%20Bikes/Relay%20Trips.xlsx?raw=true")
```

you'll rightly get an error :

```
  UserWarning: File contains an invalid specification for Trips. This will be removed
  warn(msg)
  UserWarning: File contains an invalid specification for Decriptions. This will be removed
  warn(msg)
```

use the Open XML Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office to test its validity

best bet it is to open it with Excel and re-save it as an xlsx, should correct the issue.

Comment: the file seems to be xlsx based on the extension

Comment: @Biarys indeed but an `xlsx` file is just a zip file with a collection of `XML` files, if the xml is corrupt then you'll either need to manually correct it (never recommend) or use another tool.

Comment: @Datanovice It turns out that the original file was saved as a "Strict Open XML Spreadsheet (\*.xlsx)" file, re saving as an "Excel Workbook (\*.xlsx)" file did the trick. Thanks!!